# Convert UIView transform from View A to View B

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, transform

What is the best way to convert a view's transform relative to another view's perspective?

---

**Example:**

View A has 2 child's, View B and C. View B also has a child, View D.

```
View Hierarchy
      A
     / \
    B   C
   /
  D
```

The transform on B is not `identity` and D is `"identity"`, but only if D is looked at isolated (not taking into account the transform on B).

View C has to know what the transform of view D is, relatively. In C perspective D is not `identity`.

---

I have been thinking about `UICoordinateSpace` and it's `convert` methods. How can I create similar covert methods for transform?

Help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: I see what you mean.. you're saying that D implicitly has the same transformation as its parent view (B), because B has a transformation. D's transformation relative to itself is `identity matrix`, but relative to an observer  (C), it has a transformation relative to its parent (B). You want to be able to convert D's transformation with respect to another view's (`- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect toView:(UIView *)view;`??? You can just take D's frame and use `CGRectApplyAffineTransform`.. but again, I'm not sure WHY you need its transformation relative to A or C or some observer..

Comment: @dfd [UICoordinateSpace](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicoordinatespace) is a protocol that contains `convert(_:to:UICoordinateSpace)` and `convert(_:from:UICoordinateSpace)` methods for `CGPoint` and `CGRect`. 

Objects that adopt the protocol have to implement these methods. `UIView` confirms to `UICoordinateSpace` and therefore you can convert point from view D CoordinateSpace to view C CoordinateSpace.

E.g. `viewD.convert(viewD.bounds, to: viewC)` will return a `CGRect` of view D bounds converted to view C CoordinateSpace

Comment: @JóhannHelgiÓlafsson; Then you can just take D's frame which should already have the transformation of B applied to it and convert that frame to C's frame then back to a transformation.  Similarly: https://pastebin.com/9QHMcA6D will create a transformation from one Rect to another Rect. `CGRectApplyAffineTransform` will give you a rect with a specified transform. Combining both will allow you to convert one transform from a view to another view. A transform is just a translation and scale after all.

Comment: @Brandon Yes exactly.

The reason why I need to do this is because I am masking a view with another view, which is also in view hierarchy. And a view cannot be in hierarchy and also a mask, so I need to create another view that represents the view I want to use as a mask. I achieve that with RxSwift bindings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Brandon Suggested that I should use the `UICoordinateSpace` `convert` method to convert the view's frame to the other view's CoordinateSpace and from there get the transform from the frame difference. That solution works for me but note that this does not take into account the `rotationAngle`, it will instead scale the transform to fit the rotated frame as it is not rotated.

### Solution

```
extension UIView {

    /// Returns transform for translation and scale difference from self and given view.
    func convertScaleAndTranslation(to view: UIView) -> CGAffineTransform {
        return CGAffineTransform.from(frame, to: convert(frame, to: view))
    }
}

extension CGAffineTransform {

    /// Returns transform for translation and scale difference from two given rects.
    static func from(_ from: CGRect, to: CGRect) -> CGAffineTransform {
        let sx  = to.size.width / from.size.width
        let sy  = to.size.height / from.size.height

        let scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: sx, y: sy)

        let heightDiff = from.size.height - to.size.height
        let widthDiff = from.size.width - to.size.width

        let dx = to.origin.x - widthDiff / 2 - from.origin.x
        let dy = to.origin.y - heightDiff / 2 - from.origin.y
        let trans = CGAffineTransform(translationX: dx, y: dy)

        return scale.concatenating(trans)
    }
}
```

@Brandon thank you for the help :)